# Is it possible for two apps on the same heroku account to access the same RedisToGo Server?

Tags: heroku, redistogo

Is is possible for two apps on the same heroku account to access the same RedisToGo Server? We have two apps that both need web access but have very different structures. So they can't be dyno types in the same app - but it would be really nice if one could queue jobs via Redis for the other to do.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, just use `heroku config` on the app that has redistogo in it and look for the REDISTOGO_URL config variable and then copy the value and then create a heroku config variable in the second app setting the same value

`heroku config:add REDISTOGO_URL=<value_from_app_a>`

Comment: best way to say thank you is to upvote the answer and mark question as answered :)